# Добавление элемента по номеру который я указываю через переменную N в однонаправленном списке

Tags: c

Здравствуйте подскажите пожалуйста как реализовать а то никак не могу придумать как мне реализовать добавление элемента по номеру который я указываю через переменную N в однонаправленном списке.

Вот моя структура:

```
struct prog {
char name[80];
unsigned int kol;
double time1;
double time2;

struct prog* next;
};
```

и если можно пожалуйста без классов

Comment: Я Вам придумаю. Отсчитать от начала списка N элементов и вставить туда новый элемент.

Comment: Igor, а не подскажите пожалуйста как в одно направленный список вставить новый элемент ?